# Stack variable and .contains(Object o)

Tags: java, stack, contain

Im having trouble keeping track of nodes in my stack. My nodes contain a 2d int array which contains numbers 0-20 as well as another integer measuring the cost to get to the current node state (2d int array).

currently i cant figure out how to track if my stack contains a node that i wish to skip since it is already in the stack or has been popped before so i avoid repeating the same compares on nodes that have the exact same state + costs.

if q is my stack and n1 is my current node i just popped, why wont

```
q.contains(n1);
```

ever return true?

I also tried making an ArrayList which creates a string for every node

Ex

```
1 2 4
5 3 6
0 7 8
```

Creates the string "1,2,4,5,3,6,0,7,8,". if i add this string to the array list and i use 
aList.contains(stringKey); never returns true?

I think i have to do something with an object because the contains() requires an object to be passed, and im not 100% sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contains(obj)` of any list returns `true` if it found `obj` in its list. It checks each `object` in list with the `obj` that you have provided with `equals()` method. So you need to override the `equals()` method of the object that you are using.

Example :

```
class MyObj {
    int a;
    char b;

    MyObj(int a, char b) {
        this.a = a; this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof MyObj){
            MyObj myobj = (MyObj) obj;
            if(myobj.a == a && myobj.b == b){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now it can be used in any `List` as here :

```
ArrayList<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<>();
MyObj obj = new MyObj(3, 'b');
list.add(obj);
System.out.println(list.contains(obj));
System.out.println(list.contains(new MyObj(3, 'b')));
```

**Output :**

```
true
true
```

According to good design pattern we should override `hashCode()` too when we decides to override `equals()`.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Just one question, if i was to compare a 2d int array, would i have to check each spot to compare or could i be like (a and b are int [][]) obj.a == obj.b?

Comment: You will have to use each element. Make use of `Arrays.equals(...)` for this, which is more efficient than doing it manually.

Comment: Don't forget, if you override equals, also override hashCode

Comment: @JorisHilhorst yes you are correct, according to design pattern we should override hashCode too but here I don't want to do that, The OP is just a beginner. But still I will edit my post to let him know that in practice we should override hashCode() too.

Comment: yeah just a comment that it's best practice :) drill them early :D